# I Need To Search a "dirty" text file in R and count the instances of a certain character

Tags: string, r, parsing, counting, data-processing

The data is called homicides.txt
I need to make a function count <- function(cause=Null)
which returns a certain integer
There are only a few acceptable causes, which if not present the function is meant to produce an error

`

```
count <- function(cause = NULL){
    if (cause != "Shooting" && cause != "shooting" && cause != "asphyxiation" && cause != "Asphyxiation" && cause != "asphyxiation" && cause != "Blunt Force" && cause != "blunt force" && cause != "Unknown" && cause != "unknown" && cause != "Stabbing" && cause != "stabbing" && cause != "Other" && cause != "other"){
        stop("Cause of Death not Valid")
    }
    z <- paste('Cause: ',tolower(cause))
    y <- 0 
    w <- 1
    x <- length(homicides)
for (i in x){
    if (grep(z, homicides[w])){
        y <- y + 1
        w <- w + 1

    }else{
        w <- w + 1
    }
    }

return(y)
}
```

Here is my code.  I want it to go through each line of the homicides file, inputted into R as homicides <- readlines("homicides.txt")

Then, if the cause is not "asphyxiation", "blunt force", "other", "shooting",
"stabbing", "unknown" with the first letter not capitalized or not, it needs to read the lines and return the number

I have tried `for (i in homicides)`, `for (i in length[homicides})` and other variations on that

No matter what, I get the error Error in `if (grep(z, homicides[w]))` { : argument is of length zero

I thought at first it was that if a line didn't contained the cause, it returned integer(0)

but that doesn't seem the problem.

Here is the assignment in full:
Write a function named count that takes one argument, a character string indicating the
cause of death. The function should then return an integer representing the number of
homicides from that cause in the dataset. If no cause of death is specied, then the function
should return an error message via the stop function.
 Your function should read the homicides dataset in the manner indicated above.
 The options for cause of death are \asphyxiation", \blunt force", \other", \shooting",
\stabbing", \unknown". No other causes are allowed. If a cause of death is specied
that is not one of these, then the function should throw an error with the stop function.
 Note that some homicides in the dataset do not have a cause of death listed and those
records should be ignored.
 Your function should deal with some irregularities in the dataset like capitalization.
For example \Shooting" and \shooting" should be counted as the same cause of death.
 Do not worry about spelling errors in the dataset (records with spelling errors can be
ignored)
The function should use the following template.

```
count <- function(cause = NULL) {
## Check that "cause" is non-NULL; else throw error
## Check that specific "cause" is allowed; else throw error
## Read "homicides.txt" data file
## Extract causes of death
## Return integer containing count of homicides for that cause
}
```

The function should execute as follows:

> count("other")
>   [1] 6
>   num <- count("unknown")
>   print(num)
>   [1] 10

A line of txt in the file looks like this:
39.311024, -76.674227, iconHomicideShooting, 'p2', '

Leon Nelson

3400 Clifton Ave.
Baltimore, MD 21216

black male, 17 years old

Found on January 1, 2007

Victim died at Shock Trauma

Cause: shooting

'
39.312641, -76.698948, iconHomicideShooting, 'p3', '

Eddie Golf

4900 Challedon Road
Baltimore, MD 21207

black male, 26 years old

Found on January 2, 2007

Victim died at scene

Cause: shooting

'
39.309781, -76.649882, iconHomicideBluntForce, 'p4', '

Nelsene Burnette

2000 West North Ave
Baltimore, MD 21217

black female, 44 years old

Found on January 2, 2007

Victim died at scene

Cause: blunt force

'
39.363925, -76.598772, iconHomicideAsphyxiation, 'p5', '

Thomas MacKenney

5900 Northwood Drive
Baltimore, MD 21212

black male, 21 years old

Found on January 3, 2007

Victim died at scene

Cause: asphyxiation

'
39.238928, -76.602718, iconHomicideBluntForce, 'p6', '

Edward Canupp

500 Maude Ave.
Baltimore, MD 21225

white male, 61 years old

Found on January 5, 2007

Victim died at scene

Cause: blunt force

'
39.352676, -76.607979, iconHomicideShooting, 'p7', '

Michael Cunningham

5200 Ready Ave.
Baltimore, MD 21212

black male, 46 years old

Found on January 5, 2007

Victim died at JHH

Cause: shooting

'
39.310999, -76.622023, iconHomicideShooting, 'p8', '

Ray Alston

300 West North Ave.
Baltimore, MD 21217

black male, 27 years old

Found on January 5, 2007

Victim died at UMMC

Cause: shooting

'

Comment: +1 for putting up a homework question AND showing us what you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

```
dat <- readLines("clipboard") # shortcut for copied data above
dat <- tolower(dat) # make it easy on yourself, normalize the strings right away

casues_df <- as.data.frame(
 table(
  factor(
   gsub("cause: ","", # remove "cause: " from
    dat[grep("^cause",dat)] # lines that start with cause
   )
  )
 )
)

          Var1 Freq
1 asphyxiation    1
2  blunt force    2
3     shooting    4
```

Now you can "lookup" the frequency of an event with something like:

```
dat[dat$Var1 == "asphyxiation",]$Freq
```

Now, I've done the hard work, all you need to do is create a function that does what your teacher asks you to.